# Combine variables in a string, reverse geocoding - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to get back the adress of the point where the "user" clicks on the "google map" I have implemented on my website.

I copied the source code form [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) and made a view adaptations. In the source from google, you get the "latlng" by an input field. I get it by a "event".

In my "geocode-function" I sum my "lat" and "lng" parameters together to what they would have looked like if they came out of the input field.

Here is the code:

```
  // Set variables  

  var clicklat;
  var clicklng;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;  

  // Listen for click on map

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { 
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
  clicklat = parseFloat(event.latLng.lat());
  clicklng = parseFloat(event.latLng.lng());      
  geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });

  // Geocode function   

  function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = "#{clicklat},#{clicklng}"
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])}; 
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Now, the problem I have is that `console.log(input);` gives back: `#{clicklat},#{clicklng}`. Why, the heck, my variables get not implemented there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to usea "jade" and is not working?

Anyway Here is a way to make it work:

```
// Set variables  

//var clicklat;
//var clicklng;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;  

// Listen for click on map

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { 
  placeMarker(event.latLng);

  //clicklat = parseFloat(event.latLng.lat());
  //clicklng = parseFloat(event.latLng.lng());      
  geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, event.latLng); //I add this as a parameter
});

 // Geocode function   

 function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, thelocation) {
//  var input = "#{clicklat},#{clicklng}"
//  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
//  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])}; 
geocoder.geocode({'location': thelocation}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    if (results[1]) {
      map.setZoom(11);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: results[1].geometry.location,
        map: map
      });
      infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    } else {
      window.alert('No results found');
    }
  } else {
    window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. One little problem is now left over. When i click on the map now, the marker and the adress information goes to the next "village" or bigger "city", the marker doesn´t stay at the exact "clicking-point" and gives back the full adress from there. I think it has something to do with "position: results[1].geometry.location" - do you know what i have to put in there? - I´m sorry.. im a bloody beginner

Comment: i believe because you were using the second result..or result[1], try using index 0 for the first results, so just replace all results[1] with results[0] and let me know

Comment: sadly nothing changed. Here is the demo i uploaded: 

http://www.fabiansquinobal.com/geo.html

Comment: what is wrong? I am trying this in Barcelona and everything looks fine...What is your desire behaviour exactly?

Comment: @betofarnia - I have another problem. I try to center the map with  "map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location.latlng);" after "map.setZoom(11);". Do you maybe have any advice? Thank you - I tried it without the ".latlng" aswell and it did not work